# Is the Trek Navigator 200 too hard to restore

Tags: repair, upgrades, trek

I got a freecycled Trek Navigator 200 that based on my assessment seems to be from 2004.

I have repaired one bike before and was thinking about taking the this one as a new challenge but it seems to me that this one may be too hard.

From now I noticed the bike need:

- Frame paint job
- New rear wheels (the old hub seems to be disintegrating and currently wobbles), spokes don't look great
- And a new fork...

What the fork...

From my measurements, the steering bar seems to be a 1" inch in diameter but a shocking 265mm of length.[1][2]

I was thinking about replacing the fork with a rigid but I am finding it  pretty hard to find forks with such a long tube.

Should I just give up or are odd solutions like using a 650b or a 700c fork things I should consider?

**Sources**

[1] http://www.vintage-trek.com/Trek-Fisher-Klein-Lemond/2004specmanualTrek.pdf

*Note the 235mm head tube on page 34.*

[2] https://www.bikeforums.net/19741961-post4.html

*Note the author surprise to the lenght of the tube*

Comment: The headset dimensions are interesting. Looks like the head tube is for 1 1/8 inch fork and the headset reduces it to 1 inch. So, it could be possible to fit a 1 1/8 inch headset and threadless fork. Those are intended to be cut to length and often have something like 300mm steerer tube.

Comment: @ojs thanks for the hint. I ended up giving up on the job after security another oldie to fix... (a Cypress 4) :-)